# How to update text box with new values and check the count using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, textbox, bootstrap-4

I am facing this issue, that i have to count if the number of values in text box field has exceeded 5 or not. In case it has not i can enter values, and if yes then i cant enter anymore. The screenshot of screen and html is attached. Any help would be appreciated.[image: keywords]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "keywords" in your input box is stored as a `span` with class name "tag label label-info". You can simply get the count of that element and verify it to be 5 or not:

**JAVA -**

```
List <WebElements> tags_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'bootstrap-tagsinput']/span[@class = 'tag label label-info']"));

if(tags_list.size() >= 5)
{
// do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: thanks, let me verify.

Comment: thank you @Shivam, it is working well.